# How can I have the date field render as datepicker in Orchard editor template?

Tags: orchardcms

I created a module with a content part which has some fields as date. When I render these date fields in the editor template I want them to be rendered as datepicker textboxes exactly as they are rendered when I create a custom content type with Date Time Fields using the admin panel.

is there a shapehelper or smth like that to have them rendered as datepickers and have the necessary jquery scripts be added automatically, or do I have to manually render textboxes and add the necessary js scripts to?

I am using Orchard 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the same UI as orchard provide  You only need to include below styles and scripts to your view:

```
Style.Require("jQueryCalendars_Picker");
Style.Require("jQueryUI_Calendars_Picker");
Style.Require("jQueryTimeEntry");
Style.Require("jQueryDateTimeEditor");
///////////////////////////////////

///////
Script.Require("jQueryCalendars_All").AtFoot();
Script.Require("jQueryCalendars_Picker_Ext").AtFoot();
Script.Require("jQueryTimeEntry").AtFoot();
```

and append the below script to your javascript file:

```
 $("#DateSelector").calendarsPicker({
        showAnim: "",
        renderer: $.extend({}, $.calendarsPicker.themeRollerRenderer, {
            picker: "<div {popup:start} id='ui-datepicker-div'{popup:end} class='ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all{inline:start} ui-datepicker-inline{inline:end}'><div class='ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all'>{link:prev}{link:today}{link:next}</div>{months}{popup:start}{popup:end}<div class='ui-helper-clearfix'></div></div>",
            month: "<div class='ui-datepicker-group'><div class='ui-datepicker-month ui-helper-clearfix'>{monthHeader:MM yyyy}</div><table class='ui-datepicker-calendar'><thead>{weekHeader}</thead><tbody>{weeks}</tbody></table></div>"
        })
    });
```

Or Customize it as you like to display at any time user interacts with UI

Comment: I tried adding those manually but somehow I missed one of the css files. However still I don't get a date picker popup. I don't get any script errors or any thing like that when I check the Console for javascript errors and all the js and css files are in the html.  
  
This is what use in my view:  
  
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfTrainingStartUtc, null, new { @class = "calendardatepicker" })

    And this the rendered html :

    <input class="calendardatepicker" id="Training_DateOfTrainingStartUtc" name="Training.DateOfTrainingStartUtc" type="text" value="29/10/2015 00:00:00">

Comment: Nevermind I copy/pasted the scripts and js code from DateTimeeditor.cshtml and it worked. Probably I was missing smth. Thanks for pointing me to right direction.

Comment: You could also use other custom date-pickers which have better UI than jQuery but you should care about formatting and other stuff when updating model yourself specially when  converting the UTC to local

Answer (score 2):

You can use Orchard's DateTimeEditor class to use the same editor view as the date field does, and take control over the various options (date editor, time editor). This way you also take in account updates of orchard, including jquery UI libraries.

ViewModel:

```
public class MyEditViewModel {
    public DateTimeEditor DateTimeEditor { get; set; }
}
```

In your driver (use IDateLocalizationServices):

```
public class MyPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<MyPart> {

    private readonly IDateLocalizationServices _dateLocalizationServices;
    public SchedulingPartDriver(IDateLocalizationServices dateLocalizationServices) {
        _dateLocalizationServices = dateLocalizationServices;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(MyPart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Parts_MyPart_Edit", () => {
            var viewModel = new MyEditViewModel {
                DateTimeEditor = new DateTimeEditor {
                    ShowDate = true, // if date editor should be shown
                    ShowTime = true, // if time editor should be shown
                    Date = _dateLocalizationServices.ConvertToLocalizedDateString(part.MyDate),
                    Time = _dateLocalizationServices.ConvertToLocalizedTimeString(part.MyDate)
                };
            };
        });
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(MyPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        // same as above, probably put it in a separate method to build the viewmodel
        var viewModel = new MyEditViewModel {..};

        if(updater.TryUpdateModel(viewModel, Prefix, null, null) {
            part.MyDate = _dateLocalizationServices.ConvertFromLocalizedString(viewModel.DateTimeEditor.Date);
        }

        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

And then in your Views/EditorTemplates/Parts/MyPart.cshtml:

```
@model MyNameSpace.ViewModels.MyEditViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeEditor) // this will render the editor for the date/time
```

Comment: For a quick solution I used @Shahin's suggestion and it worked but this looks like a better solution. I'll try it thanks.

Comment: Your first Editor method seems to be missing a closing `)` for the ContentShape. I'm also getting the error "Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<dynamic>'" but I'm not familiar with the notations that are being used here so I'm not sure what needs to be changed to resolve that issue. I naively tried to just return the viewModel but that evidently doesn't work.

Comment: @BauceLawyerson see edited answer. I think in the time I wrote the answer I did in from the top of my head without an actual IDE, no intellisense in stackoverflow ;)